# Which is the best way to code CSS

Tags: html, css

I have so many blocks with different sizing, padding and margin values. So I thought to create support CSS classes and combine as below;

**CSS**

```
.m-t-5 { margin-top: 5px; }
.m-t-10 { margin-top: 10px; }
.m-t-15 { margin-top: 15px; }

p-10 { padding: 10px; }
p-15 { padding: 15px; }

.f-left { float: left; }
.f-right { float: left; }
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="m-t-5 p-20 f-left lined"></div>
<div class="p-10 m-0 f-right"></div>
```

By using this all my class names are becoming big(I mean in length). So is this a good practice? please suggest me wether to continue this way or creating multiple CSS classes with its own properties.

Regards.

Comment: How many blocks do you have?

Comment: I have around 50 blocks to be used in multiple projects

Comment: Nice thought. You can also give like `thinTop`, `mediumTop` or `thickTop` instead of what you declared above. So that even if you want to change the css property values in future(like margin-top: 10 instead of 5), you can still understand how those class names will effect. :)

Comment: Looks very good to me. I follow a similar practice as well, especially for `float` and `font-size`

Comment: i believe you can expand this further, using less. the actual code would be just as long, but at least you can use variables to do padding(5), padding(10), etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @ryan, but you also need to be tricky and intelligently move around as-per your layout to reduce the code as maximum as you can. And also avoid using (-)&(_) etc... and make very simple & clean naming conventions. Please see example below:

CSS

```
.mt5 {margin-top: 5px;}
.pd5 {padding: 5px;}
/* Margin Top 5 and Padding 5 */
.mt5pd5 {margin-top: 5px; padding: 5px;}

.fl {float: left;}
.fr {float: right;}
```

HTML Markup

```
<div class="fl mt5 pd5">Welcome</div>
<div class="fl mt5pd5">Hello</div>
```

Comment: Thanks mknayab, I think this way is better

Answer (score 3):

There are a few methodologies that suggest advice here:

- [Block, Element, Modifier](http://bem.info/)
- [Scalable and Modular Architecture for CSS](http://smacss.com/book/)
- [Object-Oriented CSS](http://oocss.org/)

There's also the [HTML/CSS style guide](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/htmlcssguide.xml) that Google's own developers adhere to.

Comment: Thanks jokeyrhyme. Very useful links.

Answer (score 1):

now used to this way

as like this

```
.marginT10{margin-top:10px;}
.marginT20{margin-top:20px;}
.marginT30{margin-top:30px;}
.marginT40{margin-top:40px;}
.pull-left{float:left;}
.pull-right{float:right;}
```

Comment: Is the any reasons to avoid (-) in the class names?

Comment: no depand on your style as u wish you can write css according to you i just suggestion to you because i write this formate css ....

Comment: Thanks, i'll follow this way

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

This is perfectly fine and is very common. It actually helps to keep the [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) principle.

Second: The only 'best-practice' for coding css is to avoid inline css, but even that has exceptions. So if it works for you then go ahead and use it. (But again what your doing is considered ok practice.)

Comment: Thank you Ryan, I'll follow this way.